# Delete Excel Figures from Matlab

Tags: matlab, excel, activex, vba

I would like to directly delete all the figures in an excel file from MATLAB. I can select all the figures using activex but I cant' figure out a way to delete them.

My code:

```
filename_out = 'Libraries\Documents\TEST.xlsx'; % filename

Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application'); % open the connection

set(Excel,'Visible',1);

Excel.Workbooks.Open(filename_out); % open excel file

worksheets = Excel.sheets;

numSheets = worksheets.Count; % count the number of sheets

for s = 1 : numSheets % do a loop for all sheets

 worksheets.Item(s).Shapes.SelectAll;  % select the figure
% How to delete selection? *
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop, do something like

```
myshapes = worksheets.Item(s).Shapes;
for j = myshapes.Count:-1:1
    myshapes.Item(j).Delete
end
```

Note that we're counting down from `myshapes.Count` to 1, as the count goes down each time you remove one.

Comment: If you want the final complete solution:

worksheets = Excel.sheets;
numSheets = worksheets.Count;


for s = 1 : numSheets

   myshapes = worksheets.Item(s).Shapes;
    
    for j = myshapes.Count:-1:1
         myshapes.Item(j).Delete
    end
   
end